# AngularJS - App Controler

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On [this website](http://www.codecademy.com/en/learn/learn-angularjs/topics/routing/exercises/routing-routing-iii) i learned to write an app controller for AngularJS like this:

**Codecademy Version:**

```
app.controller
(
    'PhotoController', 
    [
        '$scope', 'photos', '$routeParams', 
         function($scope, photos, $routeParams) 
         {   
             photos.success
             (
                 function(data) 
                 {     
                     $scope.detail = data[$routeParams.id];   
                 }
             ); 
         }
    ]
);
```

But i found that it is also possible to code it like this:

**My Version:**

```
app.controller
(
    'PhotoController', 

     function($scope, photos, $routeParams) 
     {   
         photos.success
         (
             function(data) 
             {     
                 $scope.detail = data[$routeParams.id];   
             }
         ); 
     }
);
```

Both codes work, but what is the difference? Should i use the version from codecademy or mine? And why? My version is shorter and i see no disadvantages.

Comment: First version works even when scripts are minified link [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05)

Comment: While the code academy course is good, you should really read up on the angular docs about dependency injection relating to your question - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di - and check out the angular-phonecat tutorial

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your version is that it will not work with minified code. You will have to annotate your controllers and other modules to get it working. 
Your code will work unless it has not been minified but while minification your service/controllers names will get renamed and break your app.

Please refer to the following link for more information : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 1):

With your second version of your code, it will not work if minified due to the fact that with angular the variables **have to** be called `$scope, photos, $routeParams`.

If you do the 1st version it does dependency injection with any variable name.